# Cardboard case storage

Tags: garage

I have a large attic storage space above my garage.  Is there a fire hazard in storing cardboard boxes above a garage (unconditioned attic) in south Texas heat?

Comment: No fire hazard, assuming you're not storing flammables, but my greater concern is whether your garage was designed to have stuff stored above it. (I've seen cracked trusses because people have loaded stuff into the space above the garage.) Can you post a picture of the structure?

Comment: Right. South Texas roof systems are not likely to have been designed for snow loads, so I wouldn't put more than say 200 lbs of stuff in your attic, assuming it's distributed over 4-6 trusses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about cardboard auto igniting in heat, then you don't need to worry.  Paper has an auto ignition around 400 deg F.

Comment: "Fahrenheit 451" -- flash point of (typical) paper.